# Why doesn't the state value changed by useEffect come back?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (!isMobile)
            if (collectShow)
                if (closeModal)
                    if (controllModal) {
                        setShowModal (true)
                    }else{
                        setShowModal (false)
                    }
    },[isMobile, collectShow, closeModal, controllModal])

    console.log (showModal)
```

I want to keep changing the value of showModal like this,
but once changed, it stays the same even if the conditions change.
I'm new to react, so I think I used the wrong useEffect, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you dont want nested ifs. Right now your code basically means

```js
if (!isMobile && collectShow && closeModal)
  setShowmodal(controllModal)
```

So it only changes when the first condition is true

While you probably want

```js
setShowmodal(!isMobile && collectShow && closeModal && controllModal)
```

At least thats my assumption. If its not what you want I can only recommend abusing console.log to see where you are going

Comment: thank you very much. Wrong very basic JavaScript. I will study more